# iOS15 - First NavigationLink doesn't work if onAppear of new view updates ObservedObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios15

This is a really weird issue that I haven't been able to resolve.

It happens only on iOS 15 and only the 1st time I try to open this specific NavigationLink.

I have 3 SwiftUI Views:

- ContentView (entry point)
- DetailView
- ItemView

ContentView is a list of DetailViews and in detail views there can be any amount if ItemViews.

I have an ObservableObject with a `Published` property `count`, that is only accessed from ContentView. In ItemView I have function that's triggered by `onAppear`, that updates `count` in the ObservedObject.

When I open an ItemView for the first time after opening the App, it moves to the view but immediately goes back to DetailView. It doesn't happen, when I open it again, even though `count` is updated again.

I have spent a lot of time debugging this issue, but I'm out of ideas. I have tried reproducing it in a Swift Playground, but everything I've tried there seems to work as expected.

I hope someone has an idea on how I can resolve this issue, I would be most grateful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a nav link, I would highly suggest using a custom one instead. I can't understand why this is only happening in ios 15 for you, but I have had a similar bugs with the same views/logic in previous OS versions.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SwiftUI's `NavigationLink`, what do you mean by "custom one"? I pass a custom view, not a String.

Comment: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGXWC68Yb_o&t=1220s&ab_channel=SwiftfulThinking) This video should fix your issue. It shows the flaws of navlink and how to create your own custom navlink using ontapgesture, a loading view, and segue.